# How do I html-escape dangerous unsanitized input in jinja2?

Tags: python, security, escaping, jinja2

Can I do it inside the template or must it be done in python code?

I have a variable that may contain da<ngero>u&s chars. How do I escape it in jinja2?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

e.g.

```
{{ user.username|e }}
```

Pipe it through the `|e` filter

Docs:

- 2.x: [Jinja: Template Designer Documentation -> HTML Escaping](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#html-escaping)
- 3.x: [Jinja: Template Designer Documentation -> HTML Escaping](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#html-escaping)

Answer (score 24):

You could also tell the environment to autoescape everything:

```
e = Environment(loader=fileloader, autoescape=True)
```

note: in jinja1 this is auto_escape

Answer (score 10):

If you want to escape html in your programme, you can do it like this(example):

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> jinja2.__version__
'2.6'
>>> a
'<script>alert("yy")</script>'
>>> jinja2.escape(a)
Markup(u'&lt;script&gt;alert(&#34;yy&#34;)&lt;/script&gt;')
>>> str(jinja2.escape(a))
'&lt;script&gt;alert(&#34;yy&#34;)&lt;/script&gt;'
```

Comment: For later jinja2 versions use `import markupsafe; markupsafe.escape` instead, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71721006/1136208).

Answer (score 1):

Flask has a built in `tojson` filter:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#standard-filters

Answer (score -3):

You can do a string check and replace with the corresponding escaped characters.

For example: `string=I am a special character <`
Do the following:

```
string.replace("<","&lt ;")
```

Note that in your code, the space between t and ; has been eliminated. Can't eliminate this here as it will be formatted to show < instead :P

Then use jinja2 to print out the formatted string. The < should appear in your display.