# How to avoid auto escaping HTML tags with Jinja2

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have flask, jinja2 and python.
So, I'm trying to display text that is stored as markdown.
I do this

```
class Article(db.Entity):
...

    def html(self):
        return markdown(self.text) # from markdown import markdown
```

Next in my view I do this

```
html_text = article_.html()    
return render_template('article.html', article=article_, comments=comments, user=user, text=html_text)
```

And in article.html I just have this line

```
{{text}}
```

So, with data stored in db as `*im busy*` I have `<p><em>im busy</em></p>` in my browser. 
I tried to use `.replace('&lt;', '<').replace('&gt;', '>')` but it changes nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jinja2: html escape variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556554/jinja2-html-escape-variables)

Comment: It is more this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592554/disabling-autoescape-in-flask

Comment: @metatoaster yes it is. Thanks.

Comment: @metatoaster can you replace the "this question may be already..." for your link so I can press "that solved my question" on a right link?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you know safe filter?

```
{{text|safe}}
```

[Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2)