# ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, jinja2, pydash

I am getting the error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'

When trying to run code using the following *requirements.txt*:

```
chart_studio==1.1.0
dash==2.1.0
dash_bootstrap_components==1.0.3
dash_core_components==2.0.0
dash_html_components==2.0.0
dash_renderer==1.9.1
dash_table==5.0.0
Flask==1.1.2
matplotlib==3.4.3
numpy==1.20.3
pandas==1.3.4
plotly==5.5.0
PyYAML==6.0
scikit_learn==1.0.2
scipy==1.7.1
seaborn==0.11.2
statsmodels==0.12.2
urllib3==1.26.7
```

Tried

```sh
pip install jinja2
```

But the requirement is already satisfied.
Running this code on a windows system.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Jinja is a dependency of Flask and Flask V1.X.X uses the `escape` module from Jinja, however recently support for the `escape` module was [dropped in newer versions of Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/#version-3-1-0).

To fix this issue, simply update to the newer version of Flask V2.X.X in your *requirements.txt* where Flask no longer uses the `escape` module from Jinja.

```
Flask>=2.2.2
```

Also, do note that Flask V1.X.X is no longer supported by the team. If you want to continue to use this older version, [this Github issue may help.](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/4494)

Comment: a useful answer for updating Flask: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68897437/12940469

Answer (score 59):

This happens because Jinja has removed those functions in a recent version —  3.1.0 — [released on March 24th, 2022](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/#version-3-1-0).

> `Markup` and `escape` should be imported from MarkupSafe.

You have two options form here:

1. either this error comes from one of your dependency.
   The first thing you should consider is to upgrade the said dependence(s).
   If this is not possible, what you can do, from here is to downgrade your Jinja version to a version that would still include `escape`, for example, adding it explicitly in your *requirements.txt*:

   ```
   jinja2<3.1.0
   ```
2. or, your error is from code you wrote, so you can fix it by importing it from MarkupSafe, as suggested in the Jinja release notes.

   So, you should use

   ```py
   from markupsafe import escape
   ```

   instead of

   ```py
   from jinja2 import escape
   ```

Comment: Worked perfect with jinja2<3.1.0. Thanks for sharing! 
I also needed to add `werkzeug==2.0.3`.

Answer (score 16):

Simply update your Flask version, it works for me

```
Flask==2.1.0
```

Comment: how to update flask version in ubuntu?

Comment: check this guide https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-flask-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: pip install Flask==2.1.0

Answer (score 9):

So what happened to me is that I cloned a repo on github and installed flask with my virtualenv activated using the command `pip install -r requirements.txt` but when I tried to run the server thats when it have me the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'

So what I did is ran the command `pip uninstall flask` and reinstalled it by running `pip install flask` and then ran my server again, then it worked.

**SIMPLE SOLUTION**

```
pip uninstall flask
```

then

```
pip install flask
```

Comment: Fixed installing AWS SAM in a docker image today! SAVED ME!

Answer (score 5):

As per [change logs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/) for version >= 3.1.x, need to use escape from markupsafe not from jinja2

so to use `escape` do

```
from markupsafe import escape
```

Answer (score 1):

> ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'

This happened to me using Voila with jupyter notebook and solved using method below:

1. going to this directory `C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nbconvert\filters\ansi.py`
2. adding this line to the first of file `from markupsafe import escape`
3. Also change this line of code `text = jinja2.utils.escape(text)` to `text = escape(text)`

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by just downgrading jinja2 to low stable version,

```
pip install Jinja2==3.0.3
```

[reference](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/importerror-cannot-import-name-escape-from-jinja2-solved/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
!pip install --upgrade babel
!pip install --upgrade python-dateutil
!pip install --upgrade flask-moment
!pip install --upgrade flask-wtf
!pip install --upgrade flask_sqlalchemy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from html import escape
```

This is what worked for me.

Comment: SilkLife, please don't add _thanks_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).

Comment: Ok!  Can i answer in the comments?

Comment: @mozway: This appears to be a new answer, just poorly worded.