# Unable to import pandas_profiling module, because of 'escape' from jinja2.utils dependency

Tags: jinja2, pandas-profiling

```
from pandas_profiling import profile_report
```

=================================================

ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2.utils' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py)

Comment: What version of `pandas_profiling` do you have installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718167/importerror-cannot-import-name-escape-from-jinja2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `escape` module was dropped from newer versions of `jinja2`. The newer versions of `pandas-profiling` use `markupsafe` to import `escape` module (`from markupsafe import escape`). However, your version seems to already use the old import (`from jinja2.utils import escape`). You have two options:

- Try to install a newer version of `pandas-profiling`.
- Or install an older version of `jinja2`.

The following environment seems to be working:

```
Jinja2                3.1.1
MarkupSafe            2.0.1
numpy                 1.22.3
pandas                1.4.2
pandas-profiling      3.1.0
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718167/importerror-cannot-import-name-escape-from-jinja2), or this [github issue](https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling/issues/947) for more information.