# Load-balanced Docker Nginx app crashes "Exited (1)" yet Python Flash app loads manually - "ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'"

Tags: python-3.x, docker, nginx, flask, jinja2

I'm trying this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/sample-load-balancing-solution-with-docker-and-nginx-cf1ffc60e644

GitLab repo here: https://gitlab.com/ouassini/load-balancing

When I manually test both Flask app1.py and/or app2.py they both load on port 5000:

```
ubuntu@docker:~/GitLab-Repos/load-balancing/app1$ python3 app1.py 
 * Serving Flask app 'app1'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://192.168.64.5:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 900-505-536
```

However, when I try and run the docker container both App1 and App2 crash immediately and Nginx shows https://localhost:8080 as **502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.23.2**:

```
2022-11-25 14:10:29 Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-11-25 14:10:29   File "//app1.py", line 1, in <module>
2022-11-25 14:10:29     from flask import request, Flask
2022-11-25 14:10:29   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
2022-11-25 14:10:29     from jinja2 import escape
2022-11-25 14:10:29 ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
```

I found this SO post which seems to address the issue: [ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718167/importerror-cannot-import-name-escape-from-jinja2)

However, after updating the **requirements.txt** file to use `Flask==2.1.0` the issue still persists.

Comment: Have you tried a `docker compose build` after you changed your requirements file?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that worked! I ran `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up` and everything is good now. :) Please write an answer and I'll accept it .