# ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'- Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, jinja2

I am trying to run this docker-compose file for a Flask app. Facing trouble in getting the server start.
Here is the error happening:

[Docker-compose run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkyov.png)

[requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg1Qq.png)

I tried different version of jinja2 but its not working!

[Docker-compose run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkyov.png)

[requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg1Qq.png)

I tried different version of jinja2 but its not working!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718167/importerror-cannot-import-name-escape-from-jinja2)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

as speciified in the documentation  [change logs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/) under version 3.1.0 you need to import escape from markupsafe as

`from markupsafe import escape`