# Flask cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'

Tags: flask, jinja2

I wrote a very simple Flask app with docker file to up its container here: https://github.com/trouchet/appy. I use package management tool `poetry`. When I run `make start`, it outputs the following error. Please, help me discover where my flaw is

```
flask --app src/main.py run --port=8081
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Flask==1.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'flask')()
  File "/home/brunolnetto/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 534, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/brunolnetto/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2930, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/brunolnetto/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2517, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/brunolnetto/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2523, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jinja2 import escape
ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
make: *** [Makefile:99: start] Error 1
```

Comment: What version of Flask are you running? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718167/importerror-cannot-import-name-escape-from-jinja2

Comment: Upgrading Flask to latest version solves the issue. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718167/importerror-cannot-import-name-escape-from-jinja2)

Answer (score 1):

The root cause with your question may stem from a dependency management conflict between two software ecosystems. According to the error message, your jinja2 was installed using pip at the path /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jinja2/. The flask that depends on it was installed using apt at the path /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/. The versions of the two are not compatible. In fact, there is a version of jinja2 in the system that flask correctly depends on, but the Python interpreter prioritizes the jinja2 installed by pip, leading to this issue. There are typically two solutions to this problem: (1) Use sudo pip to uninstall jinja2, and then reinstall them using apt, or uninstall flask using apt and reinstall it using sudo pip. (2) Use Python's imp module to customize the path and import the flask from the apt path before importing jinja2. An example is as follows:

```
import imp
path = ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('jinja2', path)
imp.load_module("jinja2", fp, pathname, description)
```

Hope my diagnosis is helpful to you！

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).