# How do I resolve "cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'" error

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to startup Flask and I getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/meta-system/run_app.py", line 22, in <module>
    from system import FlaskApp
  File "/home/ec2-user/meta-system/system/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/home/ec2-user/meta-system/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jinja2 import escape
ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2' (/home/ec2-user/meta-system/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
make: *** [Makefile:17: up] Error 1
```

Looking at other StackOverflow questions such as [ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718167/importerror-cannot-import-name-escape-from-jinja2) and [Flask cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383191/flask-cannot-import-name-escape-from-jinja2), it looked like a simple matter of upgrading Flash and jinja2 but to no avail.  I have Flask 2.3.3:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-227 meta-system]$ pip3 show flask
Name: Flask
Version: 2.3.3
Summary: A simple framework for building complex web applications.
```

and jinja2:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-227 meta-system]$ pip3 show jinja2
Name: Jinja2
Version: 3.1.2
Summary: A very fast and expressive template engine.
```

I cannot downgrade jinja2 to something that escape/jinja2 play well together as other packages also rely on it at a certain version.

Thoughts on what I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Though it can be hard if there are many dependencies in your project, finding overall compatible packages is a way. Either upgrade all or play around to find out right ones(experiment in new test environment).

Comment: Are you sure the package is up to date in your venv?

Comment: The commands you ran are showing result of the system package which are not the same as the venv packages, more likely.